# is there a way to move vim windows in this way?

Tags: vim

I have four windows like this:

```
|         |      |      |
|   A     |      |      |
|_________|  C   |   D  |
|   B     |      |      |
|         |      |      |
```

So, how can I change them into this way?

```
|         |      |
|   A     |  C   |
|_________|______|
|   B     |  D   |
|         |      |
```

the

```
ctrl+W/J/K/L
```

thing is always moving the window to the far other side, I can't use them to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd need a macro to do it, if there were a way it would be one of the ctrl-w commands, and :help ctrl-w doesn't show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what I can think of is two steps:

1. move cursor to `C`, press `C-W c` to close the window
2. move cursor to `D`, press `:sp #<enter>`

The idea is, close one window(buffer), and reopen it in right place (by sp or vs).

glad to know if there is easier way.